# Dynamic localization files blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Here's the scenario I have. I'm working on a multi-lang application but the available languages are dynamic and returned by an API from the server. After selecting a language I should download the localization file that contains the key/value pairs to use it in my application.

My question is, does the BlackBerry localization system allow such behavior? I mean can the key/value localization files be added to the application dynamically or they have to be bundled in my COD?

If that scenario doesn't work, I would appreciate suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default resource files used to localize an application must be bundled with the application.

Instead you could use Locale.getDefaultForSystem() to return the current locale in use and based on that load the correct language from your remote source.